# sRGB on iOS OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

According to very [few related topics that I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14493502/340947) I am gathering that the exponentiation step to obtain proper lighting computations perhaps must be done within the final fragment shader on an iOS app.

I have been profiling with the latest and greatest Xcode 5 OpenGL debugger and the exponentiation of the fragment accounts for a significant amount of computation. It was the line that took the longest time in the entire shader (the rest of the performance got sucked out by the various `norm` calls needed for point-lights).

`glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB);` unfortunately does not work as `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` is not declared.

Of course the actual enum I should be using for GL ES may be different.

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html):

> The following extensions are supported for the SGX 543 and 554
>   processors only:
>
> EXT_color_buffer_half_float
>   EXT_occlusion_query_boolean
>   EXT_pvrtc_sRGB
>   EXT_shadow_samplers
>   EXT_sRGB
>   EXT_texture_rg
>   OES_texture_half_float_linear

Well, that's nice, the newest device that does not have a 543 or 554 is the iPhone 4.

From [the extension's text file](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_sRGB.txt) it looks like I can set `SRGB8_ALPHA8_EXT` to the `internalformat` parameter of `RenderbufferStorage`, but nothing is said of how to get the normal final framebuffer to apply sRGB for us for free.

Now the sRGB correction seems like the missing step to get the correct colors. What I've been doing in my app to deal with the horrible "underexposed" colors is manually applying gamma correction like this in the fragment shader:

```
mediump float gammaf = 1.0/1.8; // this line declared outside of `main()`
// it specifies a constant 1.8 gamma
mediump vec4 gamma = vec4(gammaf, gammaf, gammaf, 1.0);
gl_FragColor = pow(color, gamma); // last line of `main()`
```

Now I recognize that the typical render pipeline involves one or more renders to a texture followed by a FS quad draw, which will afford me the opportunity to make use of an `SRGB8_ALPHA_EXT` renderbuffer, but what am I supposed to do without one? Am I SOL?

If that is the case, the `pow` call is sucking up so much time that it almost seems like I can squeeze some more perf out of it by building a 1D texture to sample and use as a gamma lookup table. This texture could then be used to tweak the output color intensities in custom ways (and get a much better approximation to sRGB compared to just the raw exponentiation). But it just all seems kind of wrong because supposedly sRGB is free.

Also somewhat alarming is the absence of any mention of the string `srgb` anywhere in the GL ES 2.0 spec. [According to the makers of `glm`](http://www.g-truc.net/post-0263.html) GL ES simply ignores sRGB entirely.

I know that I have used my code to render textures (I made a basic OpenGL powered image viewer that renders PVRTC textures) and they did not get "dimmed". I think what is happening there is that due to GL ES 2's lack of sRGB awareness, the textures are loaded in as being in linear space and written back out in the same way. In that situation, since no lighting gets applied (all colors got multiplied by `1.0`) nothing bad happened to the results.

Comment: That is not entirely correct. GLES does support sRGB default frame buffers, but you are going to need another extension (an EGL extension) in order to get it. [`EGL_KHR_gl_colorspace`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_gl_colorspace.txt). It is a very new extension, so I am not surprised G-Truc does not know or hast not written anything about it.

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. As you say, it is quite new. It's sort of surprising to me how little literature there is out there currently regarding gamma correction/sRGB on iOS. Which leads me to guess that `EGL_KHR_gl_colorspace` is not a currently supported GL ES 2.0 extension. (GL 3.0 does bring sRGB support so I should be all set for that if my app requests and obtains a 3.0 context.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

iOS 7.0 adds the new color format `kEAGLColorFormatSRGBA8`, which you can set instead of `kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8` (the default value) for the `kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat` key in the `drawableProperties` dictionary of a `CAEAGLLayer`. If you’re using GLKit to manage your main framebuffer for you, you can get `GLKView` to create a sRGB renderbuffer by setting its `drawableColorFormat` property to `GLKViewDrawableColorFormatSRGBA8888`.

Note that the OpenGL ES version of `EXT_sRGB` behaves as if `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` is always enabled. If you want to render without sRGB conversion to/from the destination framebuffer, you’ll need to use a different attachment with a non-sRGB internal format.

Comment: Do you know if this is only possible on devices actually running iOS 7, and that I would need to still perform the frag shader solution for all iOS 6 devices? Or is this an option provided to me if I use the iOS7 SDK (which I am using to build an iOS 5.1-compatible app) and will also work (for free sRGB framebuffer) on iOS 5/6 devices?  (I'll update with my findings when I get around to actually testing this stuff.) It seems to me like the most reasonable route will be using the actual `EXT_sRGB` extension's functionality which should be guaranteed so long as the device supports the extension.

Comment: The extension has only been implemented on iOS7 devices, if you are deploying to anything less than that you will have to perform the gamma correction in your shader.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are getting confused between the EXT_sRGB and the ARB_framebuffer_sRGB extensions. The EXT_sRGB is the more recent extension, and is the one supported by iOS devices. This differs from ARB_framebuffer_sRGB in one important way, it is not necessary to call glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB) on the framebuffer to enable gamma correction, it is always enabled. All you need to do is create the framebuffer with an sRGB internal format and render linear textures to it.

This is not hugely useful on its own, as textures are rarely in a linear colour space. Fortunately the extension also includes the ability to convert sRGB textures to linear space. By uploading your textures with an internal format of sRGB8_ALPHA8_EXT, they will be converted into linear space when sampled in a shader for free. This allows you to use sRGB textures with a better perception encoded colour range, blend in higher precision linear space, then encode the result back to sRGB in the render buffer without any shader cost and accurate gamma correction.

Comment: Well, I am creating a 3D model rendering app which does not actually employ textures at any point. Is it still possible for me to specify the **main** framebuffer as sRGB so that it will take my (linear) fragment output and correct it to sRGB prior to displaying on the screen? I can tell that I am losing a huge amount of detail in "dark" areas due to a lack of gamma correction.

Comment: Yes, it is. All fragments rendered to the frame buffer are assumed to be in linear colour space, and will be gamma corrected. If blending is enabled, the contents of the frame buffer will be converted back to linear space prior to blending with the fragment, then converted back to sRGB again.

Comment: This does not appear to be the case, my lighting looks incorrect unless I apply a 1.8 gamma curve manually in the frag shader. I mean, I clearly need to "Switch something on" to enable sRGB write of the main framebuffer (provided by `EXT_sRGB` which doesn't really mention it...), because if I do not enable something I will and *should* get the standard OpenGL ES 2.0 behavior of pretending sRGB doesn't exist.

Comment: Then you are going to have to show your setup code, I have this working nicely with a project using GLKit, and there is no "switch on" required.

Comment: My app as it is now grew out of the old, old GLKit GL ES 2.0 demo, the one with the two green and blue cubes spinning. I am missing the "create the framebuffer with an sRGB internal format" bit certainly.

Comment: If your application was derived from the OpenGL application template, there should be some code in -[ViewController viewDidLoad:] that sets your GLKView’s drawableDepthFormat to GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24. Try adding a line to change drawableColorFormat to GLKViewDrawableColorFormatSRGBA8888.

Comment: @Pivot Fantastic, it worked. Hopefully this is a couple of free ms of speed by going to iOS7; I'll post some "benchmark" results in a separate answer when I test this across my iOS 6/7 devices

Answer (score 2):

Here are my test results. My only iOS7 device is an A7-powered iPad5, and in order to test fillrate I had to tweak my test app a bit to enable blending. That was sufficient on iOS 6.1 to prevent fragment-discarding optimizations on opaque geometry, but for iOS 7 I also needed to write `gl_FragColor.w` != `1.0` in the shader. Not a problem.

Using the `GLKViewDrawableColorFormatSRGBA8888` does indeed appear to be free or close to free in terms of performance. I do not have a proper timedemo style benchmark setup so I am just testing "similar" scenes and the removal of the `pow` shaved around 2ms off the frame time (which would e.g. take 43ms to 41ms, 22 fps to 24 fps). Then, setting the sRGB framebuffer color format did not introduce a noticeable increase in the frame time as reported by the debugger, but this isn't very scientific and it certainly could have slowed it by a half a millisecond or so. I can't actually tell if it is completely free (i.e. fully utilizing a hardware path to perform final sRGB transformation) without first building more benching software, but I already have the problem solved so more rigorous testing will have to wait.